# Left pad zeros and save the result as Integer in java.

Tags: java

Here is my code

```
Integer.pasrseInt(new DecimalFormat(0000).format(230));
```

This returns a `String` but I want to save it as an `Integer`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The left 0s are insignificant in an Integer. Just store the integer as is and left pad it with 0 when you want to present that integer in a particular format.

Comment: -1 Very confusing - your code example returns an `Integer` not a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way it that you can prepend `0`s if the characters are less than 4. Integers cannot have `0` in front. AFAIK, only `String` objects can be created by prepending `0`s to integers. Note, when you convert the `String` back to `Integer`, the prepended zeros will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's an overkill but maybe this give you an idea of why you cannot directly do what you asked:

```
public class MyInteger {

private Integer value;

public MyInteger(Integer value){
  this.value = value;
}

public String showWithPad(){
  return DecimalFormat(0000).format(value);
}

}
```

Then you do

```
MyInteger myInteger = new MyInteger(230);
System.out.println(myInteger.showWithPad());
```

And this prints

```
0230
```

As it was stated you cannot pad an `Integer` but its representation (eg the way you show it). Then you have to store the number as is (an `Integer`) and add the padding zeros when you want to represent it this way.